Continuity of principal argument on non-negative values.
$\DeclareMathOperator\cis{cis}$
In Amann's analysis Exercise III.6.9, it is asked to prove the following:

Here $S^1$ is the sphere of radius $1$ in $\mathbb{C}$, and $\cis$ is known to be lipschitz continuous. Exercise 3.3(b) is basically saying that if $X$ is compact and $f: X \to Y$ is a continuous bijection then $f$ is a homomorphism.
Following the hint, it is easy to show that it suffices to show that the inverse of the restriction of $\cis$ on $(-\pi,\pi)$ is continuous. I'm assuming the third part of the hint is letting us do  the following argument:
For each $x \in (-\pi,\pi)$, choose a compact interval $[x-t, x+t] \subset (-\pi,\pi)$. Then $\cis :[x-t,x+t] \to \cis([x-t,x+t])$ is a homomorphism, so that its inverse $cis^{-1} :\cis([x-t,x+t]) \to [x-t,x+t]$ is continuous. However, this does not directly follow that $\cis^{-1} : S^{1} \setminus \{0\}$ is continuous at $\cis(x)$, since we have not proven that $\cis([x-t,x+t])$ is a neighborhood of $\cis(x)$ in $S^{1} \setminus \{0\}$. In fact proving that it is a neighborhood is directly equivlaent to proving that $\cis^{-1}$ is continuous at $x$, so I don't see how this hint helps.
Am I missing something or are there some errors with the hint.

Indeed we have to prove that $\operatorname{cis}^{-1} : S^1 \setminus \{-1\} \to (-\pi,\pi)$ is continuous. I also do not see how the hint in (iii) gives a proof of this fact. So let us use another approach based on the continuity of $\operatorname{cis} : \mathbb R \to S^1$.
Continuity of $\operatorname{cis}^{-1}$ means that for each open $U \subset (-\pi,\pi)$ the preimage
$$(\operatorname{cis}^{-1})^{-1} (U) =  \operatorname{cis}(U)$$
is open in $S^1 \setminus \{-1\}$. Since $S^1 \setminus \{-1\}$ is open in $S^1$, it suffices to show that $ \operatorname{cis}(U)$ is open in $S^1$.
The set $C = [-\pi,\pi] \setminus U$ is compact, thus  $\operatorname{cis}(C)$ is a compact subset of $S^1$. Therefore $V = S^1 \setminus \operatorname{cis}(C)$ is an open subset of $S^1$. We claim that $V = \operatorname{cis}(U)$ so that we are finished.
Let $C' = (-\pi,\pi) \setminus U$. Then $C = C' \cup \{-\pi,\pi\}$ and we get
$$\operatorname{cis}(C) = \operatorname{cis}(C') \cup \operatorname{cis}(\{-\pi,\pi\}) =  \operatorname{cis}(C')  \cup \{-1\}.$$
Since $\operatorname{cis}$ maps $(-\pi,\pi)$ bijectively onto $\operatorname{cis}((-\pi,\pi))  = S^1 \setminus \{-1\}$ we get
$$V = (S^1 \setminus \{-1\} ) \setminus \operatorname{cis}(C') = \operatorname{cis}((-\pi,\pi)) \setminus \operatorname{cis}(C') =  \operatorname{cis}((-\pi,\pi) \setminus C') = \operatorname{cis}(U) .$$
